# Subtracting two localtime() in android

Tags: android, jodatime

Does anyone know a short-cut for subtracting two local-times in java joda?
I'm trying to compare this with my C# code where the subtractions is done easily.

```
Timespan t1 = timespan[i].Subtract(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

I'm trying to get such thing in java joda without making the conversion and then forming  the above.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#minus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod)

Comment: timespan[i] does not look like a local time (TimeOfDay). Please clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was too lazy to search the joda documentation and wanted a quick answer.
here is my solution:

```
LocalTime[] timespan = null;
int t1_Totalmiliseconds= (timespan[i].getMillisOfDay())-(LocalTime.now().getMillisOfDay());
                         PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                         .printZeroAlways()
                         .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
                         .appendMinutes()
                         .appendSeparator(":")
                         .printZeroAlways()
                         .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
                         .appendSeconds()
                         .toFormatter();
                         Period period = new Period(t1_Totalmiliseconds);
                         String now=fmt.print(period);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have now clarified what your timespan-array means (indeed of type `LocalTime`, not of timespan-type!) you can achieve a much simpler solution to get a suitable `Period`-object:

```
LocalTime lt1 = new LocalTime(14, 15); // start time
LocalTime lt2 = new LocalTime(21, 55); // or: LocalTime.now()
Period p = new Period(lt1, lt2, PeriodType.dayTime()); // in days, hours, minutes, seconds, millis 
System.out.println(p); // output in ISO-8601 => PT7H40M
```

If you want a string output then you can use the `PeriodFormatter` in your answer.

Compared with the .NET-code Joda-Time also offers just an one-liner (line 3 in my code example). The disadvantage of Joda-Time is to have just a direct constructor, not a method with an intuitive name like "Subtract" or "until" or similar. The advantage of Joda-Time is the ability to specify a so-called period type which might be missing in .NET (please correct me if I am wrong).